# Loop through value is column and delete the row if any values that starts with 35

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA for excel and I am stuck with a little problem. I trying to find a way for looping through all the values in column B in my spreadsheet which is the account number of a customer.

I then what it to delete the row with an value that starts with 35...

I usually code in PHP so it would be sub_str however I'm very new to VBA and i'm unsure.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. And if you know one language, it's real easy to pick up another...

Comment: Look up the `Left()` statement.

Comment: for that matter, look up `Excel VBA How to Loop Through Cells in Range (or Column)` ... you'll find some very useful info with that google search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub DeathAt35()
   Dim N As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = N To 1 Step -1
      If Left(Cells(i, "B").Text, 2) = "35" Then Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
   Next i
End Sub
```